# How do I create a barchart for the following table using python. I created by doing a pivot and then plotting in excel. (desired output attached)

Tags: python, dataframe, bar-chart, cluster-computing

[Please click here to view the table and the output desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jllme.png)

I have a simple dataframe and i need to create a barchart for the same. Let's say cluster 3 has 5 restaurants, then the plot should show the same. Please have a look at the image attached. I have provided the desired output

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your data a bit.
First Convert the data and represent differently.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

dct = {'clusters':[3,3,3,0,5,3,3,2,1,3,1,4,1],
'venue':['I','I','H','M','I','F','C','A','H','I','D','H','H']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
print(df)

mod = []

#modifying data
for x in np.unique(df.clusters):
    for y in np.unique(df.venue):
        tmp = {}
        temp = df[df.clusters==x] 
        k = len(temp[temp.venue==y])
        if k>0:
            tmp['cluster'] = x
            tmp['venue'] = y
            tmp['value'] = k
            mod.append(tmp)

mod = pd.DataFrame(mod)
print(mod)

#plotting figure using seaborn barplot, where hue is your venue.

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
seaborn.barplot(x='cluster', y='value', hue='venue', data=mod, ax=ax1)
seaborn.despine(fig)
plt.xlabel('Clusters')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
    clusters venue
0          3     I
1          3     I
2          3     H
3          0     M
4          5     I
5          3     F
6          3     C
7          2     A
8          1     H
9          3     I
10         1     D
11         4     H
12         1     H

modified data

   cluster venue  value
0        0     M      1
1        1     D      1
2        1     H      2
3        2     A      1
4        3     C      1
5        3     F      1
6        3     H      1
7        3     I      3
8        4     H      1
9        5     I      1
```

Graph looks like this:[image: The graph don't look as you've shown because I've taken random data.]

Comment: Thank you so much. Although I didn't use your code exactly, but seeing your code reminded me the 'HUE' functionality. So I used the following code directly to give me the final result:

ax = sns.countplot(x="Cluster Labels", hue= '1st Most Common Venue', data=clus)